# How to set database state before JMeter test run?

Tags: database, web-services, testing, jmeter

What is best way to set web-application database state before running JMeter functional test on it? DBMS and JMeter are on same machine (for test and developing purposes). DBMS is MySQL 5.5.

Comment: or how can I run any scripts before jmeter tests thread group starts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As proposed by aneroid, you could use mysqldump which will be much faster than injecting data by another format.
To do so:

- Use a [Setup Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) which will contain an [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) to run the mysqldump command

Regards

Philippe M.

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much! That`s what I search! Sadly, I can`t plus your answer.

Comment: I`m logged. "Vote Up requires 15 reputation". How can I mark your answer as solution of my question?

Answer (score 1):

If you know which data is your Test Data for **functional tests** and vs. the data required by the **application**, you could do a [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) of those tables in their 'base state' which is required before every testing execution. Then you can use that dump to 'reset' your DB to that stage before every execution. Quoting the linked page:

> The dump typically contains SQL statements to create the table,
>   populate it, or both. However, `mysqldump` can also be used to generate
>   files in CSV, other delimited text, or XML format.

If you need some tables only partially, remove those INSERT queries from the dump generated so that you can just execute the sql dump (or upload the csv, text or xml file).

Comment: That`s clear, thankts. But what a would to do to automatic set db with saved xml data before every test run? Should I write single script (i.e. bash) and run two commands (mysqldump + jmeter) whithin it?

Comment: Yes, you could put it in a bash script if you want it fully automated. You could also just execute the dump before a starting jmeter. Restoring the dump is one command and jmeter can (should) be executed in non-GUI mode, so yes, you could put the two commands into a bash file.

Comment: Ok, thank you! However I want to find method to start GUI jmeter.

Comment: Well, from the [user guide](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) `jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l test.jtl` starts in non-GUI mode. So without the `-n` it starts in GUI mode.

Comment: That`s mean I should restart jmeter every time when I want to start new test and I must use bash script that combines db setup call and jmeter starting. But I find simple solution that allows me to start tests from jmeter gui without jmeter restarting. =)